# PNG/JPG file to HBITMAP with GDI+

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I need to load an image as a HBITMAP in C++ so I can send it to a printer.
I've tried using `Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile`and then `Gdiplus::Bitmap->GetHBITMAP` however the HBITMAP returned is still empty.

I can load .bmp files fine with `LoadImage()` but this doesn't work with PNG files.

Could anyone point me to the correct way of implementing this to work with .png (and more, if possible) file types?

EDIT: CODE

```
ZeroMemory(&hBitmap, sizeof(HBITMAP));
Gdiplus::Bitmap* gpBitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(L"img.png");
gpBitmap->GetHBITMAP(0, &hBitmap);
```

EDIT 2: Solution found

```
HBITMAP GetHBITMAPFromImageFile(WCHAR* pFilePath)
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gpStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gpToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gpToken, &gpStartupInput, NULL);
    HBITMAP result = NULL;
    Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(pFilePath, false);
    if (bitmap)
    {
        bitmap->GetHBITMAP(Color(255, 255, 255), &result);
        delete bitmap;
    }
    GdiplusShutdown(gpToken);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `Gdiplus::Bitmap::GetHBITMAP` is supposed to work.  If it doesn't, then you're possibly doing something wrong.  However, we can't tell if you don't provide code demonstrating how you're using it.

Comment: Are you sure that 1. the program is defined as unicode 2. the png is in the executable directory?

Comment: I just have the png in that directory for demonstration purposes

Comment: @DavidHaim Instead of in the executable directory, the file should be in the working directory.

Comment: Are you calling `GdiplusStartup()` ?

Comment: I am, but Is `GdiplusStartup()` an essential call to have?

Comment: Have you checked whether `Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile` and `GetHBITMAP` actually succeed?  How do you know that the returned `HBITMAP` is empty?